# minimum number of lines UILabel in iOS development

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to make a cell in uicollectionview. please see these two images  [image: Image 1]  [image: Image 2]

Thats the cell of a collectionview and the first uilabel's number of line is 2. what I am trying to do is the uilabel will always take 2 lines of height regardless of the content of the uilabel, is it possible? if the text is short, second line will be blank.

If I add height constraint, the text is vertically centred. How to make it top-aligned?
[image]

Comment: You can add a height constraint on your UILabel.

Comment: Or you could append: `\n\n` to the end of your string. If the `numberOfLines` of your label is set to 2, it will always reserve the 2 lines of space.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 steps.

First select your label, click the add new constraints, and check the height constraints, as grow4gaurav said.

Next, go to the attributes inspector and set the number of lines to 0. This makes it so that the text uses as many lines as it wants. So, if the text is short, and it only uses one line, it will just use the top line. If it is longer, it will use the bottom line too.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Alex. The problem is if I set the height the text is vertically in the center. Is there any way to make it top-aligned?

Comment: There's no direct API to set vertical alignment on a UILabel, but you can get similar effect by changing it's frame. In addition to doing yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0 also do yourLabel.sizeToFit()